# Как правильно использовать Material компоненты с разными стилями?

Tags: css3, angular2, material-design, scss

Страница логина у меня с темным фоном, а остальные с светлым. Я использую angular material components. Как использовать один и тот же компонент **"Input"** но с разными стилями, соответствующими фону?

Я думаю просто перебить через **"!important"** это не лучшая практика

Comment: А может пример кода хоть какой,а?

Comment: а что в офф документации не так к материалу?